# Highcharts.js - Dynamically disable given category

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts.js is it possible to disable/enable a given category by clicking on it? In the same way as you can disable/enable a given series in a legend by clicking on it.

If not, what is the next best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling a category by clicking on it is not supported in Highcharts by default. To acheieve the wanted result you need to add custom code. For example, in `render` event you can add `click` event to `xAxis` labels and update the chart with new categories and data:

```
var H = Highcharts,
    categories = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    data = [1, 2, 3];

chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var chart = this;

                H.objectEach(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(tick) {
                    if (tick.label) {
                        H.addEvent(tick.label.element, 'click', function() {
                            data.splice(tick.pos, 1);
                            categories.splice(tick.pos, 1);

                            chart.update({
                                series: [{
                                    data: data
                                }],
                                xAxis: {
                                    categories: categories
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: data
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8wfx5yve/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!